# Driver binding and "/sys/bus/pci/drivers" -- are they related

Tags: linux, driver, embedded-linux, pci

In my device driver for wifi internet pci device there is  `bind` file. Its a binary file
present here /sys/bus/pci/drivers/iwlwifi/bind

I like to know does every device driver has bind file (pci once)? What  are they?  Are they just interface like sysfs? Can they be used for talking to driver like I open this file and using mmap it to map it into userspace buffer, does it make sense?

On Kernel.Org it says

> Driver binding is the process of associating a device with a device driver that can control >it. Bus drivers have typically handled this because there have been bus-specific structures to >represent the devices and the drivers. With generic device and device driver structures, most >of the binding can take place using common code.

what `most of the binding can take place using common code` means?

Comment: It is not a very well documented feature for binding devices to drivers from userspace. See the LWN article [Manual driver binding and unbinding](https://lwn.net/Articles/143397/) from 2005.

Comment: @IanAbbott I like to ask u can a single device driver be all of the three 1) char driver 2) pci driver 3) net_dev driver?

Comment: I don't think it can be all three, but it can be a PCI driver (or any other bus client driver) plus one of the others. Character devices have file system interfaces in the form of _character special_ files, but network devices have no file system interface.

Comment: @IanAbbott `I don't think it can be all three,` basically I like to ask u do u say it to the level of "it can't be done no matter what, No use, technically not possible". Then It sounds like pci drivers don't allow mapping of userspace buffer using `MMAP` then why there is a function in pci.h and the only function that can relate to memory mapping of user space buffer to kernel virtual memory. And in Linux Device Driver book the chapter contains info on this that this is possible. PCI device and MMAP can work. at least it sounded like it. Please clarify

Comment: @IanAbbott `pci_mmap_page_range` in pci.h

Comment: @IanAbbott I know there are challenges in sending packets with MMAP-ed buffer but I think I can be totally doable for reading packets because to get MMAP included in driver is to have file OPs enabled and that will come from char device driver/or may be block drivers(I will find out). I simply want to map the buffer and as the packets are read those packets are written to memory (kernel virtual page) which I will have as a result of vm_area_struct's vm_start vm_end and offset. I just have to maintain these fields to be updated if there is remapping of buffer. Does it make sense

Comment: I don't really know what you are trying to do, but it seems unrelated to the original question.

Comment: @IanAbbott yes u were right. But I just like to ask u can I register driver as pci driver plus filesystem driver. I think this way real applications work. They bypass kernel stack. So I just open file and read and write to pci. I found number of hotplug drivers tutorials online that explains this work.